# Group by a column and then perform specific operation within groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is a subset of the data I am working with:

[image]

I have a problem where I need to group by the "MATNR_BATCH" column and then perform an operation within that group. I need to make sure that the groups/subsets have an equal number of 'FULL' and 'NF' values in the "FULL_IND" column. In this instance, I would like to keep the first two rows and get rid of all the other rows with the 'FULL' value in the "FULL_IND" column.

I would like to keep the row with the 'FULL' value that has the closest proximity to the row that has the 'NF'. Proximity is decided by the "BIN_LOC" column. In this case, the first row has a "BIN_LOC" of 34 and the second row (with 'NF') has a "BIN_LOC" of 38.

Can someone please help me figure out a way I can code this? I am new to python and not sure how I can iterate through groups and perform this operation.

Comment: Equal amount of "FULL" and "NF" do you they can be more than one of each?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.sort_values(by="BIN_LOC",inplace=True)
```

First sort the values by BIN_LOC

```
df["cc"]=df.groupby(["MATNR_BATCH","FULL_IND"]).cumcount()
```

We groupby all elements that have the same MATNR_BATCH and FULL_IND.

We create a new column called cc which corresponds to result of the `.cumcount()` function. This function returns the enumarator of the occurrence in the groupby combination.

After we define the minimum number of occurrences of "NF" and "FULL" for each group.

```
grp=ndf.groupby(["MATNR_BATCH"])["FULL_IND"].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).min(1).reset_index()
```

this creates a new Dataframe, which keeps the minimum value.

After we merge this dataframe with previous one.

```
df=df.merge(grp,left_on="MATNR_BATCH",right_on="MATNR_BATCH")
```

After we filter out only the examples which have a lower enumerator "cc" than the minimum for that group "0"

```
df[df["cc"]<df[0]]
```

I think this should answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Borut. Actually, this will only partially work because I'm not just looking for the first occurrences only, but what I would ideally like is an equal number of NF to FULL within a group. 

So for example, if a group has 4 NF values and 8 FULL values, I would like to keep all four 4 NF values along with 4 other FULL values that are in close proximity to the respective NF values and get rid of the other 4 FULL values. I hope this explanation makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Hi, I've adapted the answer now.